# Variable Variables in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of `n` strings. For example, `strings = ('path1','path2',path3')`

I want to create `n` variables that are equal to functions on these strings. For example:

```
s1=pygame.mixer.Sound('path1')
s2=pygame.mixer.Sound('path2')
s3=pygame.mixer.Sound('path3')`
```

I've looked this up a few times before and answers always seem to refer to dictionaries. I am not too familiar with dictionaries although I know their basic function. I don't know how I would use a dictionary to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with dynamically creating variables is: how do you plan on referring them in your code? You'll need to have some abstracted mechanism for dealing with `0..n` objects, so you might as well store them in a data type that can deal with collections. How you store them depends on what you want to do with them. The two most obvious choices are `list` and `dict`.

Generally, you'll use a `list` if you want to deal with them sequentially:

```
paths = ['path1', 'path2', 'path3']
sounds = [ pygame.mixer.Sound(path) for path in paths ]

# play all sounds sequentially
for sound in sounds:
    sound.play()
```

Whereas `dict` is used if you have some identifier you want to use to refer to the items:

```
paths = ['path1', 'path2', 'path3']
sounds = { path: pygame.mixer.Sound(path) for path in paths }

# play a specific sound
sounds[name].play()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a dictionary. Use `map`.

```
s = map(pygame.mixer.Sound, strings)
```

The above statement will call `pygame.mixer.Sound` with each of the strings in `strings` as arguments, and return the results as a list. Then you can access the variables like you would access any item from a list.

```
s1 = s[0] # based on your previous definition
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is you use a dictionary (or a list) *instead* of doing that.  The simplest way is with a list:

```
sounds = [pygame.mixer.Sound(path) for path in strings]
```

You then access them as `sounds[0]`, `sounds[1]`, `sounds[2]`, etc.